# ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:controller=>"vendors", :action=>"vendors"}?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my test, I'm trying to call

```
get :vendors
```

but the error I get is

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:controller=>"vendors", 
    :action=>"vendors"}
```

I do have the following in routes.rb

```
match '/vendors', :to => 'vendors#index'
```

so I don't get why it's looking for the (non-existent) "vendors" action instead of using "index" like it's matched. Can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you told it to?

The test is already contextualized, presumably with `describe VendorsController`, so saying `get :vendors` tells it to get the Vendors#vendors action.  It isn't saying "get the /vendors URL", it's going straight to the controller.

In general, you run `get :action` not `get :controller` nor `get :matched_route_name`

Comment: So :index in this particular test will get Vendors#index, correct? And in another test, say Customers, :index will get Customers#index?

Comment: as long as it's within a describe block for that controller.

Comment: Okay. I was under the impression that get looked for the route of the same name: ex, get :about looked for /about. I'm still very new to ruby on rails.

Comment: In a controller test, you're testing the controller.  That would be testing the routes, which can be found [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-0/docs/routing-specs)

Answer (score 2):

you should be doing

```
get :index
```

[Here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs) is an example of controller test in rspec